# 'app name' specifies a minimum os of version 4.3, which is too high to be installed on the iPhone.  4.2 isn't an option

Tags: xcode, ios

```
'app name' specifies a minimum os of version 4.3, which is too high to be installed on the iPhone
```

This is the error I am receiving when I attempt to deploy my application to my iPhone, which is on the latest version, 4.2.  I have searched everywhere in an attempt to find a solution to this issue, and everything simply says to change the build to target the previous OS.  However...

[image]

...I do not see 4.2 as an availible option.  4.2 is the highest version I can update my iPhone to, and 4.3 is the lowest version of the SDK I have.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set the `deployment target` of the project to eg. iOS 4.0.

Comment: How do i set the deployment target? It does not show ios 4.0 to me :(

Answer (score 0):

You only have the 4.3 SDK installed, so you can do as JustSid says and set your **Deployment Target** to something lower than what your device has installed.